# Setting a LIMIT before JOINs of tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

client_purchases:

```
id_sale | id_client | timestamp
```

files_purchases:

```
id_sale | id_file
```

So with one purchase of the client he can buy many files and the files can be bought several times.

I select what I want like this:

```
SELECT cp.id_sale, fp.id_file 
FROM client_purchases AS cp 
   JOIN file_purchases AS fp 
   ON cp.id_sale = fp.id_sale;
```

Works just fine. What I get is something like this:

```
id_sale | id_file 
   1         1
   1         2
   1         3
   2         1
   3         1
```

Now to make sure that it doesn't take forever to look through my database if it grows I wanted to limit the amount of rows.

```
SELECT cp.id_sale, fp.id_file 
FROM client_purchases AS cp 
    JOIN file_purchases AS fp 
    ON cp.id_sale = fp.id_sale 
LIMIT 0,25;
```

Whick returns me 25 rows. But what I acctually want is 25 different "`id_sale`". So is there a method to tell SQL to count the `DESTINCT`values of a column and stop if that value reaches a specified number? And I do need to be able to set the start and end value of the `LIMIT`.

Comment: Do the LIMIT part in a sub-query.

Comment: There is no such general feature in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JOIN + Subquery

```
SELECT cp.id_sale, fp.id_file 
   FROM (SELECT id, id_sale FROM client_purchases ORDER BY id LIMIT 25) AS cp 
JOIN (SELECT id FROM file_purchases ORDER BY id LIMIT 25) AS fp 
    ON cp.id_sale = fp.id_sale
```

However this may speed up your query or it may make it go even slower. It all depends on what kinds of indexes you have and how many records you have in the table.

What seems fast with 100 records might be slow with 100M records and vice verce.

Answer (score 2):

There is no feature in general.  You can do limit the number of ids using a subquery:

```
SELECT cp.id_sale, fp.id_file 
FROM (SELECT cp.*
      FROM client_purchases cp 
      LIMIT 25
     ) cp JOIN
      file_purchases fp 
      ON cp.id_sale = fp.id_sale ;
```

Normally, there would be an `ORDER BY` before the `LIMIT` so the query returns consistent results.

However, this is not a *general* solution, because the 25 ids chosen in `client_purchases` may not match anything in `file_purchases` (they may match in your case, but perhaps not in general).